# Write the planes equation when given parametric form.

Tags: linear-algebra

This should be an easy question:

Lets say we have a plane $(P)$ equation on parametric form:

$(P) : x,y,z = (0,2,0) + t(0, \frac{-4}{3}, \frac{1}{3}) + s(\frac{1}{3}, \frac{-4}{3}, 0)$

We want to write this plane on the form $Ax + By + Cz + D = 0$.

My way of doing this calculation is to write out the determinant of the matrix with the equations from the parametric form, like this:

$$A = \left( \begin{matrix} x-0 & 0 & \frac{1}{3} \\ y-2 & \frac{-4}{3} & \frac{-4}{3} \\ z-0& \frac{1}{3} & 0 \end{matrix}\right )$$

After some calculations this gives me the following result: $\frac{4}{9}x - \frac{1}{9}y+ \frac{4}{9}z - \frac{2}{9} = 0$

Now my math book  says that the correct answer is : $4x - 1y+ 4z - 2= 0$

What have I done wrong? (Or is there an error in my text book, it has happen before...)

Thank you!

Comment: You did nothing wrong: multiply your whole equation by $\;9\;$ and...voila!

Comment: Hahaha that was why it didnt make sense! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As DonAntonio said in the comment above, multiply the equation by 9 and you have the answer!